# Coloring vertices using GraphPlot

Tags: graphs-and-networks, color

I have the following problem: I used `GraphPlot` to plot my adjacency matrix.
I divided my nodes in three groups: `A = {...}, B={...} and C={...}`. I would like to color the nodes conditioning on them belonging to group A (Blue), B (Red), C (Grey).
How do I do that?

Example:
I have $12$ nodes distributed in three groups as follows: $ A=\{1,4,5,8\}, B=\{2,3,6,7,9,10\},C=\{11,12\}$. I want to color the nodes in $A$ blue, the ones in $B$ red and the ones in $C$ grey.
I have of course a $12$x$12$ adjacency matrix $M$ and I use `GraphPlot[M]` to plot the graph.
Thank you.

Comment: Please include an example

Comment: @rm-rf I have just added an example, thank you!

Comment: Please look up HighlightGraph and use Graph instead of GraphPlot.  There's no built-in function named PlotGraph.  If you meant GraphPlot, please make sure that you are precise and you type the correct names in this question.  This makes the difference between a working and a non-working command.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the notation Pinguin Dirk you could also use `VertexStyle` in `AdjacencyGraph`

```
aa = {1, 4, 5, 8}; bb = {2, 3, 6, 7, 9, 10}; cc = {11, 12};
vs = Join @@ 
   MapThread[Thread[#1 -> #2] &, {{aa, bb, cc}, {Blue, Red, Gray}}];
mm = RandomChoice[{0, 1}, {12, 12}];
AdjacencyGraph[mm, VertexSize -> 0.4, VertexStyle -> vs]
```

[image]

**EDIT**

If `GraphPlot` is what is desired then:

```
GraphPlot[mm, 
 VertexRenderingFunction -> ({#2 /. vs, Disk[#1, 0.1]} &)]
```

Answer (score 5):

Let's say you have some random matrix, such as:

```
mm = RandomChoice[{0, 1}, {12, 12}];
```

and the lists

```
aa = {1, 4, 5, 8}; bb = {2, 3, 6, 7, 9, 10}; cc = {11, 12};
```

Now, [`GraphPlot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/GraphPlot.html) can be used to plot an adjacency matrix, (docu: GraphPlot[m]
generates a plot of the graph represented by the adjacency matrix m.)

Thus, using in particular, [`VertexRenderingFunction`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/VertexRenderingFunction.html), we can do:

```
GraphPlot[mm, ImageSize -> Large, 
     VertexRenderingFunction -> (Text[
     Framed[#2, 
         Background -> 
             Which[
               MemberQ[aa, #2], LightRed, 
               MemberQ[bb, #2], LightBlue, 
               MemberQ[cc, #2], LightGray, 
               True, Pink]], #1] &)]
```

I chose `LightRed` etc for better readability. Obviously, lot's of formatting can be done from this point to make it look nice.

[image]

(a small aside: try not to use single letter upper-case names for variables. E.g. `C` is already taken by the system)