# Color Specified Vertices in LayeredGraphPlot

Tags: graphs-and-networks

Can vertices S and R9 (for example) be fill colored (say red or black) in a `LayeredGraphPlot`?

```
edges = {S -> R9, S -> R4, S -> R1, R1 -> R2, R2 -> R3, R3 -> R4, 
   R4 -> R5, R5 -> R6, R6 -> T, R9 -> T, T -> S};

LayeredGraphPlot[edges, Left, VertexLabeling -> True, 
 EdgeRenderingFunction -> ({Black, Arrowheads[0.03], 
     Arrow[#1, 0.4]} &), 
 VertexRenderingFunction -> ({White, EdgeForm[Darker[Blue]], 
     Disk[#, .4], Black, Text[#2, #1]} &)]
```

Comment: have you seen this question: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/33409/coloring-vertices-using-graphplot/33427#33427

Comment: Why don't you just use `Graph[..., GraphLayout -> "LayeredDigraphEmbedding", VertexStyle -> {1->Red, 2->Green, ...}]`?

Comment: I prefer the orientaton options LayeredGraphPlot allows such as Left, Top, etc ... the graph layout you show is nice - being parallel edges. Is there a way to shift that orientation as in the LayerGraphPlot?

Comment: Look up GraphLayout, same options are available.

Comment: yes; good recommendation. I was looking at this in IGraph-M

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the option `"Orientation"` with `"LayeredDigraphEmbedding"` layout:

```
Graph[edges, 
 GraphLayout -> {"LayeredDigraphEmbedding", "Orientation" -> Left},
 VertexSize -> .6,
 VertexLabelStyle -> 16,
 VertexStyle -> {_ :> Directive[White, EdgeForm[Darker[Blue]]], S -> Red, T -> Green},
 VertexLabels -> Placed["Name", Center],
 EdgeStyle -> Directive[Black, Arrowheads[{{0.03, .8}}]], 
 ImageSize -> Large]
```

[image]

Alternatively, wrap the desired vertices with `Style`

```
Graph[VertexList[edges] /.{S -> Style[S, Red], T -> Style[T, Green]}, edges, 
 GraphLayout -> {"LayeredDigraphEmbedding", "Orientation" -> Left},
 VertexSize -> .6,
 VertexLabelStyle -> 16,
 VertexStyle ->  Directive[White, EdgeForm[Darker[Blue]]],
 VertexLabels -> Placed["Name", Center],
 EdgeStyle -> Directive[Black, Arrowheads[{{0.03, .8}}]], 
 ImageSize -> Large]
```

> same picture

Comment: Fantastic ... thank you!

Answer (score 5):

In the specific case requested, by writing:

```
edges = {S -> R9, S -> R4, S -> R1, R1 -> R2, R2 -> R3, R3 -> R4, 
         R4 -> R5, R5 -> R6, R6 -> T, R9 -> T, T -> S};

color = ConstantArray[RGBColor[1, 1, 1], 150];
fct[t_] := color[[Total[ToCharacterCode[ToString[t]]]]]
fct[S] = LightRed;
fct[R9] = LightBlue;

LayeredGraphPlot[edges, Left, VertexLabeling -> True, 
                 EdgeRenderingFunction -> ({Black, Arrowheads[0.03],
                                            Arrow[#1, 0.4]} &),                     
                 VertexRenderingFunction -> ({fct[#2], EdgeForm[Darker[Blue]], 
                                              Disk[#, .4], Black, Text[#2,#1]}&)]
```

I get:

[image]

which is what is desired.

---

Wanting to satisfy the needs requested in the comments, by writing:

```
edges = {S -> R9, S -> R4, S -> R1, R1 -> R2, R2 -> R3, R3 -> R4, 
         R4 -> R5, R5 -> R6, R6 -> T, R9 -> T, T -> S};

colorules = {{"S", "T", LightRed}, 
             {"R1", "R3", "R5", "R9", LightBlue}, 
             {"R2", "R4", "R6", LightGreen}};
fct[t_] := Last[colorules[[Position[colorules, ToString[t]][[1, 1]]]]]

LayeredGraphPlot[edges, Left, VertexLabeling -> True, 
                 EdgeRenderingFunction -> ({Black, Arrowheads[0.03],
                                            Arrow[#1, 0.4]} &),                     
                 VertexRenderingFunction -> ({fct[#2], EdgeForm[Darker[Blue]], 
                                              Disk[#, .4], Black, Text[#2,#1]}&)]
```

I get:

[image]

which is what is desired.

Comment: Very nice! Is there a way to modify fct[t_]? Instead of writing fct[S] and fct[R9} as separate lines, if you want S, R2, R5, R9 all the same color (say light red) then can you write code for fct[S,R2,R5,R9}?

Comment: TeM: Wonderful; thank you for sharing your creative approaches. I've learned a lot ... prg